# Why is the inside div going outside the outer div and current page view with position fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a specific `width` and `height` in pixels. I have another div inside it which takes `100%` of both the `width` and `height` of the outer div. When I don't have `position: fixed` on the inside div, it takes the correct (`100%`) `width` of the outer div. However, when I set `position: fixed` to it, the div goes beyond the outside div boundaries. I am not sure why.

Code:

```css
#outer-div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}

#inner-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
}

#bottom-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div">This is some text</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom-div">I am at the bottom to allow page to scroll.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the maximum height and width of the parent element, you can inherit this.
So apply `width: inherit` and `height: inherit` to the fixed element.

```
#inner-div {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is because `position: fixed;` takes it out of the normal document flow so the `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` doesn't take the parent divs' width and height.

You can use `width: inherit;` and `height: inherit;` instead.